# How to write Latin special symbol to CMD?

Tags: batch, cmd.exe, encoding

How to write this "Ƭ"(It looks like normal T but it isn't normal T!) symbol to CMD. It automatically changes to "?"
I tried changed Encoding with **chcp** but still changes to "?"

<sup>To clarify for the OP, it's...</sup>

[image]

Comment: Try to use `chcp 65001` (UTF-8) with Lucida console fonts. Note also that the command prompt actually understands these characters, just can't display them correctly...

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/how-to-use-unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line) may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the console with `chcp 65001` (UTF-8) and using `Lucida console` as the font.

Note also that the command prompt actually understands these characters, just can't display them correctly.